# How to access internal representation of JSONb?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

In big-data queries the intermediary "CAST to text" is a performance bottleneck... The good binary information  is there, at the JSONb datatype: **how to rescue it?**

Typical "select where" example:

```
 with t(x,j) as (select 'hello','{"flag1":true,"flag2":false}'::jsonb) 
 SELECT x FROM t 
 WHERE (j->>'flag1')::boolean AND NOT((j->>'flag2')::boolean)
```

The the "casting to text" is a big loss of performance. Ideal is a mechanism to do direct,  from JSONb to Boolean, something as

```
 WHERE (j->'flag1')::magic_boolean AND NOT((j->'flag2')::magic_boolean)
```

---

PS: it is possible using C++? Is possible a `CREATE CAST` C++ implementation to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature is implemented in [Postgres 11:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11.html#id-1.11.6.8.5)

> E.4.3.4. Data Types
>
> [...]
>
> Add casts from JSONB scalars to numeric and boolean data types (Anastasia Lubennikova)

[Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=deb1a0b465962fff18d39343a6f58980)

Comment: hum... Please, see @Ancoron analysis, the news about pg v11 are not about performance, seems only a syntax sugar.

Comment: @Ancoron - Your interpretation of the query plan is wrong. `j -> 'flag1'::text` is **not** the same as `(j -> 'flag1')::text`. In query plans constants (in this case `flag1`) are automatically cast to `text`.

Comment: Point taken. Yes that's true, my fault for misinterpreting the explain here. I just took a look into the code myself and it actually is a real boolean extraction directly from the JSON structure: [jsonb_bool](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c;h=0ae9d7b9c54bbd5ffdc622d604832cd8c0632e50;hb=refs/heads/REL_11_STABLE#l1941).

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

Performance-wise it's best to use `#>` with an appropriate index covering all JSON attributes including type conversions (to avoid type conversions when accessing the index): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4da77576874651f4d2cf801142ae34d2

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_flags_btree_jsonb ON t ((j#>'{flag1}'), (j#>'{flag2}'));
```

Times (all selecting the same 5,195 rows out of 1,000,000):

```
->>::boolean | ~75 ms
->::boolean  | ~55 ms
@>           | ~80 ms
#>           | ~40 ms
```

**Scalability**:

Interestingly, a local test with 40M rows (all cached in memory, no I/O latency here) revealed the following (best) numbers out of 10 runs (excluding the first and last run) for each query:

```
->>::boolean |  222.333 ms
->::boolean  |  268.002 ms
@>           | 1644.605 ms
#>           |  207.230 ms
```

So, in fact, the *new* cast seems to slow things down on larger data sets (which I suspect is due to the fact that it still converts to `text` before converting to `boolean` but within a wrapper, not directly).

We also can see that the `@>` operator using the `GIN` index doesn't scale very well here, which is expected, as it is much more generic than the other special-purpose indexes and hence, needs to do a lot more under-the-hood.

However, in case these special purpose `btree` indexes cannot be put in place or I/O becomes a bottleneck, then the `GIN` index will be superior as it consumes only a fraction of the space on disk (and also in memory), increasing the chance of an index buffer hit.

But that depends on a lot of factors and needs to be decided with all  accessing applications understood.

**Details**:

Preferably use the `@>` containment operator with a single `GIN` index as it saves a lot of special-purpose indexes:

```sql
with t(x,j) as (select 'hello','{"flag1":true,"flag2":false}'::jsonb) 
 SELECT x FROM t 
 WHERE j @> '{"flag1":true, "flag2":false}'::jsonb;
```

...which gives a plan like:

```
                        QUERY PLAN                         
-----------------------------------------------------------
 CTE Scan on t  (cost=0.01..0.03 rows=1 width=32)
   Filter: (j @> '{"flag1": true, "flag2": false}'::jsonb)
   CTE t
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=64)
(4 rows)
```

As an alternative (if you can afford creating special-purpose indexes and the resulting write penalty) use the `#>` operator instead of `->` or `->>` and by that skip any performance-costly type conversions, e.g.

```sql
with t(x,j) as (select 'hello','{"flag1":true,"flag2":false}'::jsonb) 
 SELECT x FROM t 
 WHERE j#>'{flag1}' = 'true'::jsonb AND j#>'{flag2}' = 'false'::jsonb;
```

...resulting in a plan like:

```
                                               QUERY PLAN                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CTE Scan on t  (cost=0.01..0.04 rows=1 width=32)
   Filter: (((j #> '{flag1}'::text[]) = 'true'::jsonb) AND ((j #> '{flag2}'::text[]) = 'false'::jsonb))
   CTE t
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=64)
(4 rows)
```

So, no more implicit type conversion here (only for the given constants, but that's a one-time operation, not for every row).

Comment: Thanks, a good clue for old Pg versions. For Pg v11, a good news (!), it solved the problem, as showed by @Klin answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all benchmarks/demonstrations (!). Commenting after your edition: you used PostgreSQL v11?  The conclusion is that there is [a "lie" at E.4.3.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11.html#id-1.11.6.8.5)?

Comment: Yes, I am using PostgreSQL 11. No, it is not a lie, the type conversion is really new for JSONB in v11, it's just not implemented any better than casting a text to a boolean. Looking at the explain plans, it is clear that the more rows you have, the slower the type conversions will make it. I just did another test with even more rows, because I saw a trend here to verify...

Comment: Hi, thanks the reply (!). Yes, only a "lie" (quoting) about performance, it is a "sugar syntax" but not a real serious implementation... Perhaps need some votes to say "hey, performance is also important!" to the PostgreSQL dev. team.